# Wordpress PHP Include

Tags: wordpress

*EDIT SOLVED* The code `<?php ob_start(); ?>` put before any other output seemed to solve the problem.

I have a problem with errors appearing on a page on my site.

I am including 3 php files before any HTML output which is.

```
<?php
include_once("rpw_includes/dtd_site_root.php");
include_once("rpw_includes/dtd_remote_module_classes.php");
include_once("rpw_includes/rpw_remote_module_classes.php");
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
```

That code is in my header.php file and all works fine on my index file but when i go onto another page which also calls the same header file i get these errors.

```
Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at C:\xampp\htdocs\barnet\wp-content\themes\barnet\search-results.php:7) in C:\xampp\htdocs\barnet\wp-content\themes\barnet\rpw_includes\dtd_remote_module_classes.php on line 15

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at C:\xampp\htdocs\barnet\wp-content\themes\barnet\search-results.php:7) in C:\xampp\htdocs\barnet\wp-content\themes\barnet\rpw_includes\dtd_remote_module_classes.php on line 16

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at C:\xampp\htdocs\barnet\wp-content\themes\barnet\search-results.php:7) in C:\xampp\htdocs\barnet\wp-content\themes\barnet\rpw_includes\dtd_remote_module_classes.php on line 17
```

Any ideas?

EDIT*

search-results.php

```
<?php 
/*
Template Name: Search Results
*/
?>
<?php ob_start(); ?>
<?php get_header(); ?>

<div id="page-search-hold">
<Div id="page-search"></div>
</div>

<?php 
$module_obj= new RPW_results_obj();
$module_obj->write_html(); 
?> 

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

With the ob_start(); added the errors dissapear but i get about a 20px margin before my body starts like there should be erros but they are just not showing?

Comment: As with all the other 50 kajillion versions of this question on the site: one or more of your pages is doing output before PHP reaches the session_start(), causing this error. Look at line 7 of search-results.php and start tracking things down from there.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cannot modify header information - headers already sent, Why its happening](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1827314/cannot-modify-header-information-headers-already-sent-why-its-happening)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that the other page that includes `header.php` has the include as the very first line.

Comment: I have edited the question to include the search-results.php i cannot put it at the first line as i need the Template Name? Any Ideas?

Comment: I can add <?php ob_start(); ?> before the get_header but it seems to leave a blank before the header starts in the webview?